# Pushdown Automata

Tags: pushdown-automaton

How would I write a pda for 0^m 1^n, where |m| >= |n|; the number of 0's is greater than or equal to the number of 1's?

I was thinking of:

- if you see a 1 or 0, push it on to the stack
- if you see another 0 or a bunch of 0's, push it on to the stack
- if you see a 1, push it on to the stack
- if you see another 1 after that, pop it off of the stack

But, I don't think this is right. Can someone help please?

Comment: This could be a question better fit for http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the extra bit of info, I'm new to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the assignment correctly, then you are making this way to complicated. 0^m 1^n means a bunch of 0's followed by an bunch of 1's, but there is no legal string with a 0 after you have seen a 1. First you put a sign on the stack so you know when it's empty (ususally the #). After that you basically need to count the 0's (push them onto the stack) and when you see a 1, pop from the stack. When the input has finished you check whether the stack is you have any 0´s or the symbol that you put on the stack in the beginning.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I was thinking of doing it this way at first, but I wasn't sure if I was supposed to push on all the 1's and then pop the zeros or if it was vice versa -- now I know. Thanx!!

Answer (score 2):

consider the case of when you have an equal number of 0's to 1's.

Let's start it off easy. You can either start with a 1, or start with a 0. This gives us a union of two different languages where number of 0's is greater than the number of 1's and vice versa.

So, the empty string is also valid (this gives a clue that the first state would be a final state).

Next, we observe that we can eventually have an equal number of 0's and 1's going up and down.

Consider the string:

010101 or 101010. you noticed it always goes back to the empty stack. This is easy to deal with.

Basically you have a PDA where the start start is also the accepting state.

I'm not sure if you know the notation, so i just keep it in plain english.

you have 3 states, q0, q1, q2.

q0 is the final and initial starting state.

q0 -> q1 has 1 transition 1, e -> $ (read a 1, push a $ symbol for the empty stack).

q1 has a self loop of 0, 1 -> e and 1,e,1 (if you read a 0, pop a 1), (if you read a 1, push a 1).

There is one more transition back to the starting state q0.

q1 -> q0 0, $ -> e (read a 0, the stack is now empty) We have equal number of 0s to 1s at this point.

You do this for state q2, except pushing and popping 0's instead. So everything is just opposite with 1s and 0s.

You can then non-deterministically have any number of 0's, I'll leave this up to you. Hint: you can create 1 self loop somewhere to take care of this. It's really just 1 more state you need to add to get an equal number or greater than the number of 0's to 1's

=====================

So in plain English you need to consider two cases where you start with a 1 or 0 first. Then if you end up with an empty stack again, go back to the initial/final state and see if you have a 1 or 0 again.

Example:

10010011

Read a 1 first. Then you read a 0, so it's like you start all over again, this time with the string:

010011

Read a 0 this time, read a 1, start all over with:

0011

Read a 0, read a 0, push a 0, read a 1, pop a 0, read another 1 (stack is now empty), go back to initial/final state.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, your answer and the answer below helped a lot. Happy programming =D.